# Cucumber y Java, duda en uso de scenario outline o dataTables

Tags: java, cucumber

Estoy implementando un scenario outline con Cucumber, para validar varios reportes web dependiendo de ciertos datos enviados su respuesta va a ser una, u otra dependiendo del <*value*> enviado.

Ya que son muchos (+100 aprox) y cada uno recibe diferentes valores (tanto en cantidad de valores, como en tipo de su valor), y su respuesta no varia siempre es **presentar una pagina**, pensé en lo siguiente puede ser valido.

Agrego ejemplos de los set de datos, pero no tengo muy claro como o cual se encuentra correcto.
Gracias..

```
Background:
Go to AppTest.

Feature: AppTest
Scenario: a user signed in login the AppTest.
Given selected a valid <reportWeb>.
When enter <allValues> obligatories.
And press button 'Aceptar'.
Then the <reportWeb> appers.

Examples1:
|reportWeb|allValues|
|report1|value1|value2|
|report2|value1|value2|value3|value4|
|report3|value1|value2|value3|value4|value5|value6|
|report4|value1|


Examples2:
|reportWeb|
|report1|
|report2|
|report3|
|report4|

|allValues|
|value1|value2|
|value1|value2|value3|value4|
|value1|value2|value3|value4|value5|value6|
.
.
.
.
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ninguno de tus dos ejemplos va a funcionar, porque es necesario que el nro. de columnas sea igual en todas las files, pero por lo que veo |allValues| puede tener un nro. variable de valores. 
Entonces vas a tener que hacer un procesamiento extra en tu step, se me ocurren dos maneras:

- Separa los valores con otro separador, por ejemplo `*`:

```
Then the reportWeb appears with values: 
|reportWeb|allValues                  |
|report1  |value1*value2*value3       |
|report2  |value1*value2*value3*value4|
```

Luego en tu step vas a leer eso como un solo string, vas a tener que separar cada valor y conmpararlos con lo que retorna tu reporte.

- Pon todo en forma de arrays

```
Then the reportWeb appears with values: 
|key                  |values | 
|reportWeb[0]         |report1| 
|reportWeb[0].value[0]|value1 |
|reportWeb[0].value[1]|value2 |
|reportWeb[1]         |report2| 
|reportWeb[1].value[0]|value1 |
|reportWeb[1].value[1]|value2 |
```

Y en tu step lees las lineas de la tabla y vas extrayendo los valores de los arrays. 
Hay varias maneras de leer una tabla en Cucumber, así que tienes que buscar la que más te convenga.

Comment: Hola, muchas gracias por tu respuesta. la primera forma que me comentas el separador podría ser una coma? tipo CSV o enviar un CSV?

Comment: Puedes usar lo que quieras, siempre y cuando ese separador no aparezca nunca en los valores de tu reporte.

Comment: Gracias, Alex.!